# Journal entries of rent

Tags: accounting, check, rent

How will be the journal entries of these rental transaction:
We are giving post dated cheque for payment of rent.
Our total rent is example:

- 12,000 and giving 4 PDC [Post Dated cheque] each 3,000 and landlord(XYZ CO.)
- en-cash this every three month by the landlord

How to post this entries in accounting system

1. When we giving cheque to xyz co. at beginning
2. When xyz co. en-cash this PDC
3. At the beginning of every 3 month coming 2 months rent is pre-paid so how it will be

Answer (score 1):

You should post the unused (prepaid) rent to a prepaid asset account and expense it as used at the beginning of each month it becomes due. The current month can be expensed right away as it is being "used up" and can be posted to "rent expense".

Always match your expenses and revenue; lookup the Matching Principle for more details. This means you recognize the expense when the service (rent) is rendered.